# My plot is nested in another plot, and negative values are saturated using a diverging colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

When making a plot using plt.subplot, my plot is nested within another plot, leading to an extra set of axes with ranges 0-1 and cutting off my colorbar.

Additionally, when using a diverging colorbar, all negative values are falsely saturated.

I have used this code format before without having an additional set of axes.

Is there another way to make this kind of plot without using plt.subplot if that is causing the issue?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib
import cmocean
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import cartopy
import matplotlib.colormaps as colormaps

july = h5py.File('data/CCS_Colour_Kahru/chl/1km/daily/2016/Daily_Chlorophyll_July.mat','r')
daily_chl_july = july.get('daily_chl')
lat_july = daily_chl_july.get('Latitude')
lon_july = daily_chl_july.get('Longitude')
chl_july = daily_chl_july.get('chl')
date_july = daily_chl_july.get('date')
data_july = daily_chl_july.get('data')
lat_july = np.array(lat_july)
lat_july = lat_july[0]
lon_july = np.array(lon_july)
lon_july = lon_july[0]
chl_july = np.array(chl_july)
inside_lat_july = np.where(lat_july>=(32.9))
lat_july = lat_july[inside_lat_july]
lon_july = lon_july[inside_lat_july]
chl_july = chl_july[inside_lat_july]
inside_lat_july = np.where(lat_july<=(34.05))
lat_july = lat_july[inside_lat_july]
lon_july = lon_july[inside_lat_july]
chl_july = chl_july[inside_lat_july]
inside_lon_july = np.where(lon_july>=(-118.96))
lon_july = lon_july[inside_lon_july]
lat_july = lat_july[inside_lon_july]
chl_july = chl_july[inside_lon_july]
inside_lon_july = np.where(lon_july<=(-117.54))
lon_july = lon_july[inside_lon_july]
lat_july = lat_july[inside_lon_july]
chl_july = chl_july[inside_lon_july]

mean_chl = np.nanmean(chl_july, axis=1)
remove_nan = ~np.isnan(mean_chl)
mean_chl = mean_chl[remove_nan]
chl_july_mean = chl_july[remove_nan]
lat_july_mean = lat_july[remove_nan]
lon_july_mean = lon_july[remove_nan]

for i in range (0,31,1):
    day = i+1
    chl_now = chl_july_mean[:,i]
    remove_nan = ~np.isnan(chl_now)
    chl_now_clean1 = chl_now[remove_nan]
    lon_now_clean1 = lon_july_mean[remove_nan]
    lat_now_clean1 = lat_july_mean[remove_nan]
    mean_chl_clean = mean_chl[remove_nan]
    if np.size(chl_now_clean1)==0:
        continue
    anomaly = chl_now_clean1 - mean_chl_clean
    print('min')
    print(anomaly.min())
    print('max')
    print(anomaly.max())
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,10))
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
    ax.set_extent([-118.96,-117.54,32.9,34.05]) 
    im = ax.scatter(lon_now_clean1, lat_now_clean1, norm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-20, vcenter=0, vmax=20), c=anomaly, cmap='PiYG')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND,zorder=4,color='gray')
    ax.set_title("Chlorophyll Anomaly 2016 July "+str(day),fontsize=25)
    ax.set_xlabel("Longitude",fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel("Latitude",fontsize=20)
    xticks = np.linspace(-118.96,-117.54,5)
    yticks = np.linspace(32.9,34.05,5)
    ax.set_xticks(ticks=xticks)
    ax.set_yticks(ticks=yticks)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    im.set_clim(0.1,1.5)
    ax.coastlines()
    plt.savefig('frankieleelopez/0124anomaly72016'+str(day))
    plt.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPC02.png)

Comment: You could replace `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,10))` by `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))` to prevent to create the `ax` twice.

Comment: Did you check whether the values in `TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-20, vcenter=0, vmax=20)` make sense for the values you encounter in your data?  Now, everything smaller than -20 will be colored dark pink.

Comment: The ```plt.subplots() ``` is for creating multiple axes objects at once. Use the ```plt.subplot()``` or ```fig.add_subplot()```.

Comment: @JohanC I found the bug causing the colorbar issue, I was accidentally setting a lower limit.

Comment: @JohanC when using fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10)), I get the error.     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Figure object

Comment: @relent95 when using plt.subplot() I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Figure object

Comment: You need to read the API reference and check what they returns. Do like this ```fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10)); ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())```

Comment: @FRANKIELOPEZ Those errors only appear when you would write `fig, ax = plt.figure(...)` instead of `fig = plt.figure(...)`. "unpack" means putting the result of the function into two or more variables, which won't work when the result is only one thing.  See also e.g [here](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/tuple-unpacking/)